# Crash after using openCV SurfFeatureDetector

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to use the SurfFeatureDetector of OpenCV 2.4.12. From how the crash appears, I think I am doing something wrong. That's a simplified snippet of code which shows the relevant parts:

```
{
    cv::SiftFeatureDetector     siftDetector;
    cv::SurfFeatureDetector     surfDetector(400);
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>   siftKeypoints,surfKeypoints;

    try
    {
       siftDetector.detect(fiducial,siftKeypoints);
       surfDetector.detect(fiducial,surfKeypoints);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
       return;
    }
    ...
    return;
}
```

The crash happens sometimes durign return when the vector of cv::KeyPoints of surfKeypoints is destructed on leave. Strange thing: it happens only sometimes. And: both surfKeypoints and siftKeypoints containvalid data but it seems only surfKeypoints causes problems.

So it seems it tires to deallocate/destruct some data on exit, that are no longer there. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you might have to create those objects using `SurfFeatureDetector::create` and so on

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz create() expects a string as parameter - what string is required here?

Comment: if you are using OpenCV v2.x, stop and switch to 3.4 at least, 4.x is better. 2.x support has ended several years ago.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, in 2.4.12 it expects a parameter, elsewhere I get "error C2660: 'cv::Feature2D::create': function does not take 0 arguments" as class Feature2D defines "CV_WRAP static Ptr<Feature2D> create( const string& name );" in features2d.hpp!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz this function must have worked in 2.4 too - so how? 3.x is not an option for mee as this desastrous huge library (instead of several smaller ones like in 2.4) is a mess

Comment: "huge"? I'm sorry but what? very little changed in the layout of the modules of OpenCV between v2 and v3.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz in 2.4 OpenCV consisted of several smaller libraries where one would not have to ship all of them but only the ones that contained the required functions. In 3.x this was replaced by one single library, containing all the stuff. For me this means the total size of my software packace becomes tree times bigger - just because I would have to use this big single library instead of the few, small required ones. That's what I call "huge" comparing to 2.4

Comment: still wrong. `opencv_world` is a *choice* in the build process. if you don't want everything in one shared object, you can have `opencv_core` and all the other modules as individual shared objects. both choices are supported and neither is preferred. use `cmake-gui` and make sure that `BUILD_opencv_world` is **unchecked**.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sorry but I neither want to build the complete OpenCV stuff for my own nor want I discuss some other stuff not related to my question. So when you do not have an answer, feel free to ignore my posting!

Comment: I never used `SurfFeatureDetector::create()` in 2.4. I think it starts working in 3.0. When I worked with 2.4, I used exactly your code for creating the descriptor and never ran into a problem. A slight difference was that I used `int minHessian = 400` and then `cv::SurfFeatureDetector surfDetector(minHessian);` like in the [documentation](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/1999312/the-opencv-tutorials-release-242-opencv-documentation) p.283. But this should not make any difference.